# Picking out an ID that is not related in both columns

Tags: mysql

Need to pull an ID from col 2 where col 1 is not related to col 2 and vise versa

```
ID |  col1  |  col2  |
______________________
 1 |  20    |   19   |
 2 |  20    |   22   |
 3 |  20    |   23   |
 4 |  19    |   20   |
 5 |  22    |   20   |
 6 |  23    |   20   |
 7 |  20    |   26   |
-----------------------
```

The values (20, 19), (20, 22) and (20, 23) are all related, so those should be skipped, leaving the row with ID = 7

I am using 20 as a session variable were i can pull the value from both columns were 20 is entered.  but i want to only grab the 26. since 20 is not in col2 with relation to 26.

Looking for this result

```
ID |  col1  |  col2  |
______________________
 7 |  20    |   26   |
-----------------------
```

please help!

Comment: SELECT * FROM relations WHERE col1 = 20 OR col2 = 20

Comment: dont know how to compare 2 columns were they are related to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT col2 FROM table WHERE col2 NOT IN (SELECT col1 FROM table GROUP BY col1)`

Comment: this worked but i would like to only pull from a session variable were it equals 20

Comment: SELECT col2
FROM table
WHERE col2 AND col1 = 20  NOT IN (SELECT col1 FROM table
GROUP BY col1) getting no results

Comment: You can't do `col2 AND col1 = 20`, it's `WHERE col1 = 20 AND col2 NOT IN ...`

Comment: that did it @Guy i been staring at this monitor for 5 hours now i am about to pull my head off.

Comment: Glad I could help you, if you could be kind enough to accept the answer I'd most appreciate it :-)

Comment: thanks for your help you saved me 5 more hours, i am pretty sure.

Comment: @user2105318, You accept an answer by pressing the little V mark near the answer that you think is fit for your question.

Comment: my bad, first time user, i am glad i found this site